# Nautilus shows me Error, when I try to open a Folder as administrator

Tags: nautilus, 21.10, gvfs

When I try to open a directory as an administrator, I see [this message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/litLM.png):

> Unhandled error message:
> GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.Policykit1.Error.Failed:
> Unix process subject does not have uid set

Do you have any tips on how to solve this?

Comment: Is the directory (or file) that you’re trying to open as admin on a Samba share or NTFS partition? 

Comment: this is a directory

Comment: I get that much. I’m attempting to determine if this is a specific issue (that I’ve seen before) or something else. Are all of your storage devices using Ext4, ZFS, or something else?

Comment: they are using ext4. my solution was to kick out nautilus and use nemo instead :)

Comment: It seems [this upstream issue](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gvfs/-/issues/515) on gvfs, a [fix was released](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1935734)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right way to do it is to install an updated version of `gvfs` (special thanks to [doc_willis](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/qoyyv5/comment/hjr4nd2/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntuhandbook1/gvfs -y && sudo apt update && sudo apt install gvfs -y && sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:ubuntuhandbook1/gvfs -y
```

And after that, restarting your pc is required to apply the changes:

```
sudo reboot
```

Comment: If you're running Pop!_OS you have to add gvfs-fuse to the apt install command, since pop-desktop depends on that, and it has been changed to new packages.

The command then becomes:
`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntuhandbook1/gvfs -y && sudo apt update && sudo apt install gvfs gvfs-fuse -y && sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:ubuntuhandbook1/gvfs -y`

Comment: This worked perfectly me on PopOS 21.10.
For those curious how to test this. One of the two below should trigger opening the /etc/hosts file and nautilus `gedit admin:///etc/hosts` or `xed admin:///etc/hosts`